If $\sum a_n$ is divergent , $b_n \uparrow \infty $ then $\Sigma a_n b_n $ is divergent?
If $\sum a_n$ is divergent, $b_n$ is unbounded and increasing then $\sum a_n b_n $ is divergent?
I think it is true.
Given $\sum a_n$ is divergent, so the sequence of partial sums $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k $ is divergent.
Thus $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall k\in \mathbb{N} , \exists m_k , n_k $ such that $| S_{n_k} - S_{m_k} |> \epsilon$.
Let $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k =\sum_{k=1}^n (S_{k+1} - S_k)b_k$.
Let $k$ be large enough such that $n_k > m_k \implies b_{n_k} > b_{m_k}>0$.
Now I want to show $| T_{n_k} - T_{m_k} | > \epsilon \times \lambda $, where $\lambda $ is some constant but unable to proceed with the telescoping nature of $S_n$.
I am mainly facing problem with the sign of $a_n$.
Or is the assertion false? Any hints would be appreciated.

$a_{2n}=0, a_{2n+1}=n, b_{2n}=n, b_{2n+1}=0$.

@JMP Your $b_n$ is not increasing.

The case $b_n=n$ follows from this. See if this works for general $(b_n)$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800490/if-suma-n-converges-does-that-imply-that-sum-fraca-nn-converges?noredirect=1

@geetha290krm can you please elaborate ?

Suppose $b_n=n$. Your question asks if convergence of $\sum na_n$ implies convergence of $\sum a_n$. Equivalently it asks if convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies convergence of $\sum a_n/n$. This is true and it is proved in the link I gave.

I have checked that the proof in the link works for any $(b_n)$.

Hi @geetha290krm, nicely found and I think that's worth writing as an actual answer to this question.

This question is similar to: If $\sum a_n$ converges and $\left{b_n\right}$ is monotonic and bounded, then $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Sorry @MaximilianJanisch sir , I can't connect my question with your linked question . I mean $b_n$ is bounded there. Should I take $\frac 1{b_n} $ and think of the contrapositive of my statements ? Hints Please .

@user-492177 Yes your last sentence is precise: Take $\frac{1}{b_n}$ and consider the contraposition of your statement!

As mentioned by @Maximilian in the comments, this follows by taking the contrapositive of this question and replacing $b_n$ with $1/b_n$. For completeness, here's a short (equivalent) proof: assume for contradiction that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges. Since $1/b_n$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded (for $n$ sufficiently large), Abel's test implies that
$$ \sum a_nb_n \cdot 1/b_n = \sum a_n $$
also converges. This contradicts the assumption.
